# Combining CURL and simple html dom

Tags: php, curl, simple-html-dom

I have been working with CURL to scrape websites for a while and also Simple HTML DOM. I experienced that CURL is much better for scraping websites. However I really like the simplicity of Simple HTML DOM. So I figured why not combine the two, I tried:

```
require_once('simple_html_dom.php');

    $url = 'http://news.yahoo.com/';

    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $curl_scraped_page = curl_exec($ch);

    $html = new simple_html_dom();
    $html->load($curl_scraped_page);


    foreach($html->find('head') as $d) {
        $d->innertext = "<base href='$url'>" . $d->innertext;
    }

    echo $html->save();
```

I did my best but it doesn't work. What else can I try?

Comment: @rid Sorry should have clarified. I mean it outputs as if only the 'simplehtmldom part' is working. Im missing images and some javascript functionality. If I scrape with CURL only, the page looks different. I do get all the images and other stuff. So that tells me the CURL is not 'effective' somehow

Comment: are you talking about head tag?? because a html page contains only one head tag and you are trying to use it in foreach loop. It should be $d = $html->find('head',0);

Comment: The page you are crawling has relative paths to all its css and javascript files. you have to replace them with absolute path.

Comment: @Manish Jangir Hi I clarified for @ rid but he deleted..anyway its not about the head, thanks fot noticing though:)

Comment: @Manish Jangir Hi its not about that, I did not put the whole script in my question but in the actual script the urls are replaced, so thats not the problem

Comment: The load() function of simple_html_dom() is removing stuff like `<script>` and `<style>` from the input.

Comment: very usefull question @Youss. Thank you

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try changing this:

```
$html->load($curl_scraped_page);
```

To this:

```
$html->load($curl_scraped_page, true, false);
```

The problem is that simple_html_dom removes all \r \n by default and in this case it breaks javascript code since yahoo don't end it with a semicolon.

You can see this error at the browser console and you can also see that simple_html_dom removes linebreaks viewing the source.

Comment: You saved my life:-) THANK YOU very much, I hope people wil upvote this, awesome

Comment: I think he should also add some more curl_setopt such as `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);`

Comment: @luke_mclachlan can you please tell me why it would be better to add that ? Thank you

Comment: @ThunderBoy I wish I could remember why, it was many years since I used this script. sorry.

Answer (score 1):

I think I would add a function to the class

```
function loadWithoutRemovingStuff($str, $lowercase=true, $stripRN=true, $defaultBRText=DEFAULT_BR_TEXT, $defaultSpanText=DEFAULT_SPAN_TEXT)
{
    $this->prepare($str, $lowercase, $stripRN, $defaultBRText, $defaultSpanText);

    while ($this->parse());

    $this->root->_[HDOM_INFO_END] = $this->cursor;
    $this->parse_charset();

    return $this;
}
```

and then call that function instead of the default `load` function.

Or, since everything is public in this class,

```
 $html = new simple_html_dom();
 $html->prepare($str, $lowercase, $stripRN, $defaultBRText, $defaultSpanText);

 while ($html->parse());
 $html->root->_[HDOM_INFO_END] = $html->cursor;
 $html->parse_charset();
```

but the first way is better (cleaner)

Comment: Any idea on how to call the function with simple HTML DOM?

Comment: My suggestion was you edit the simple html dom class and add the function I've typed above. You can't call it yet because it doesn't exist.

Comment: Hi your second code gives me `Fatal error: Call to protected method simple_html_dom::prepare() from context '' in /home/mywebsite.nl/public_html/proxy.php on line 25` line 25 is: `$html->prepare.....`

Comment: You mean like this `$html->load(loadWithoutRemovingStuff);`..(sorry Im an idiot)

Comment: The class is in the file that you're using, the `simple_html_dom.php`. Right after the `load` method, paste the method that I wrote above, and then call `$html->loadWithoutRemovingStuff()`.